# How to sort a tensor by first dimension

Tags: python, sorting, pytorch, tensor, torch

I have a 2D tensor and I would like to sort by the first dimension like this example:

```
a = torch.FloatTensor(
   [[5, 5],
    [5, 3],
    [3, 5],
    [6, 4],
    [3, 7]])
```

And I expected this result after sorting:

```
a = torch.FloatTensor(
   [[3, 5],
    [3, 7],
    [5, 3],
    [5, 5],
    [6, 4]])
```

Is it possible to do this in pytorch? I know that is possible to do it in numpy, but I want do it in GPU using torch.

Comment: `values, _ = a.sort(0)`

Answer (score 14):

Sort by first column and use the indices to then sort the whole array:

```
a[a[:, 0].sort()[1]]
```

Output:

```
tensor([[3., 5.],
        [3., 7.],
        [5., 5.],
        [5., 3.],
        [6., 4.]])
```

And if you really need it interleaved:

```
b = a[a[:, 1].sort()[1]]
b[b[:, 0].sort()[1]]
```

Output:

```
tensor([[3., 5.],
        [3., 7.],
        [5., 3.],
        [5., 5.],
        [6., 4.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
torch.stack(sorted(a, key=lambda a: a[0]))
```

Output will be:

```
tensor([[3., 5.],
        [3., 7.],
        [5., 5.],
        [5., 3.],
        [6., 4.]])
```